# Processing objects in order in docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I want to process objects in the order they are written in a word document. Objects I have encountered are paragraphs, text in paragraphs, runs in paragraphs, text in runs, tables, and paragraphs in a table's cells. So far I have two useful programs. 
One which goes through the document's paragraphs and acquires the text of the paragraph; stored in a list indexed by [paragraph #]. This same program has the ability to gather the text from runs;stored in 2D list indexed by[paragraph#][run#], but I have not found the runs more useful than the whole text of the paragraph. 
My second program goes through the whole document and finds tables. When it has a table it goes through the table by row, cell, and the paragraph in the cell.

Now these seem like great building blocks for my goal. I would like to gather text in order. Abstractly, as if a blinking text cursor was being commanded to move by a person holding down the right arrow on a keyboard. As the text cursor moves over objects it is storing them by several indexes labeling the # of the object and the type of the object.

Say I have the sub functions paragraph_read and table_read. Say the document has this order of objects:     . I'd like to go through these and perform my sub functions in this order: paragraph_read, paragraph_read, table_read, paragraph_read

I would like to know if my program can move through a document object by object like a cursor swiping right.

Help is greatly appreaciated. Thanks.

-Chris

Comment: There's some discussion and code here that describes that: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40. Be sure to look to the end where some updates were made to accommodate the latest version.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks for the pointer. -Chris

Comment: @scanny I am having trouble understanding the code on this page. Could you talk me through? Or give me a hint on how to do something with it?

Comment: @scanny Specific questions I think are important: What should the document I am reading be stored as? What should I be storing parent as?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There are some new methods in `python-docx` that take care of much of the detail here:

[`Document.iter_inner_content()`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.iter_inner_content) - provides access to the `Paragraph` and `Table` objects in a document, in document order:

```
for block_item in document:
    if isinstance(block_item, Paragraph):
        ... process paragraph ...
    elif isinstance(block_item, Table):
        ... process table ...
```

A table cell is also a block-item container and has the same method. This allows recursing into tables if you want that.

Header and Footer objects are also block-item containers and have this method.

A Section is not a block-item container per-se, but does have this method for when you want to iterate through the document section-by-section.

---

You need to add this function to your code somewhere convenient:

```
from docx.document import Document
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.table import _Cell, Table
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph


def iter_block_items(parent):
    """
    Yield each paragraph and table child within *parent*, in document
    order. Each returned value is an instance of either Table or
    Paragraph. *parent* would most commonly be a reference to a main
    Document object, but also works for a _Cell object, which itself can
    contain paragraphs and tables.
    """
    if isinstance(parent, Document):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")

    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)
```

Then you use it like this:

```
document = Document('my_document.docx')

for block_item in iter_block_items(document):
    if isinstance(block_item, Paragraph):
        do_paragraph_thing(paragraph=block_item)
    elif isinstance(block_item, Table):
        do_table_thing(table=block_item)
    else:
        # raise an exception or do nothing or whatever. This branch would
        # only be reached on an unforeseen error.
```

Comment: I am getting an Attribute Error: 'CT_Document' object has no attribute '_body'

Comment: @Chris sorry, should be 'body' without leading underscore. I've updated code.

Comment: you are great help. It sure worked with that modification. I figured out do_paragraph_thing(block_item,Paragraph) is a place holder for my function and what is stored in the block_item. I'm still working on tailoring up the program as a whole, but this vital part of the program is buttoned down. The problematic body is nearly fitted! :)